# sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: not accurate?

Tags: iphone, ios

`sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` don't seem to be returning me the correct width. After these codes are executed, I see that part of the string in the label is chopping off, which means I've to manually add a few pixels to the size. Am I missing something?

I've a UILabel:

```
theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, LABELWIDTH, LABELHEIGHT)];
theLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
theLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[theLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:16]];
theLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
theLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentLeft;
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I tried to programmatically modify the size of the label using the following:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(LABELWIDTH, 10000);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [someString sizeWithFont:theLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:theLabel.lineBreakMode];

theLabel.text = someString;

CGRect newFrame = theLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
newFrame.size.width = newFrame.size.width+50;
theLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: Well, first of all, `someText` and `someString` should be the same. Are they pointing to the same NSString?

Comment: yes they are. i made a change to make it clearer.

Comment: Is this inside of a UITableViewCell?

Comment: hi @Mr. Berna, i'm trying to use sizeToFit, but I'm still not sure why the size of the label is always smaller which chops off a part of the text inside. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well, the first thing I'll say is that there are some very useful ways to deal with frames that you currently aren't employing. For example, your code,

```
CGRect newFrame = theLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
newFrame.size.width = newFrame.size.width+50;
theLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Can be rewritten with functions from [CGGeometry](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html),

```
CGFloat widthOffset = 50.0f;
theLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(CGRectInset(theLabel.frame, widthOffset, 0.0f), widthOffset / 2.0f, 0.0f);
```

However, if your code worked as it was intended, you would not need to do this at all. You can go two routes,

```
[theLabel sizeToFit];
```

Or, this should also work,

```
theLabel.frame = CGRectMake(theLabel.frame.origin.x, theLabel.frame.origin.y, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);
```

No where in your earlier code did you change the width of theLabel to match the expected width. Notice, you wrote `newFrame.size.width = newFrame.size.width+50` and that should be `newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width`.

Comment: i'm trying to use sizeToFit, but I'm still not sure why the size of the label is always smaller which chops off a part of the text inside. any idea?